# On users search, where do the languages displayed come from?

Tags: support, profile-page, user-search

When I search for users on the User Search feature on StackOverflow.com, it shows a listing of languages under the user's point total for the week.

[image: John Skeet User Search result]

Where do these language come from? For example, mine shows `css, jquery, javascript`. Yet, I've given PHP, Java, C++, etc answers, and I have many language favorite tags.

So, are these languages somehow associated with my profile? If so, how can I edit/influence them.

Thanks.

Comment: A few quick test cases indicates that it's not the tags you have the highest total score in, as was my first guess.

Comment: @Servy How can I see that btw?

Comment: The "tags" section on the user's profile shows the total score of tags they've posted in, in sorted order.

Comment: It could be the 3 tags you have the highest total score in over a given period of time, which is why it doesn't sync up perfectly with their profile page, which only displays the "all time" values for their tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are the user's top-score tags (keep in mind that score refers to answers only) for the current time period selected. Pay attention to the time frame buttons at the top right of the Users page. It rarely *ever* defaults to the "all" time frame, and tends to somewhat randomly select which time frame to view at first (when you don't have one explicitly selected).

Comment: Oh, I see the part I missed was `for the current time period selected`

Comment: Pay attention to the time frame. You are probably in "week" mode. In "all" mode, it shows your top tags as [tag:php], [tag:jquery], and [tag:javascript], which matches the information on your [tags tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1195273/crush?tab=tags).

Comment: Yes, I see my mistake. Thanks!